# How to connect two monitors to my lenovo g50-30 laptop

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

> I have lenovo(g50-30) laptop  with one HDMI and one VGA port

I want to connect two monitors to my laptop.

1st one connect with VGA cable and 2nd connect with HDMI.

I tried hard but can'tconnect two monitors at same time which displays three screens(*laptop + VAG + HDMI*).  I can see either screens, laptop+VGA or laptop+HDMI.

How can i connect all three screens?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That laptop doesn't support your desired configuration.

You can use a "USB to VGA Adapter" to add extra monitors.

Comment: can i get extended(not clonned) all these three screens using usb to vga adapter?